# Javascript convert numbers into date

Tags: javascript

I am getting an input as in

`23071996` being `DDMMYYYY` in date.

or

`07231996` which is `MMDDYYYY`

Now I want to translate this input to a date to see if this date is valid or not.

From this question, I got how we can check if it is valid date or not but I am not sure how I can translate this to `23071996` or `07231996` to actual date

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using [substring()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring).

Example:

```js
var date = '23071996';

function convertDate(date) {
    if(date.length !== 8) return 'Invalid Date'; // Checks if date is valid in terms of length
    var day = date.substring(0, 2);
    var month = date.substring(2, 4);
    var year = date.substring(4, 8);

    return { day: day, month: month, year: year };
}

var convertedDate = convertDate(date); // Converted date

function convertToDateObject(convertedDate) {
    return new Date(convertedDate.year, convertedDate.month, convertedDate.day);
}

var trueDate = convertToDateObject(convertedDate); // Date as JavaScript object, this might be useful
```

Converting this to the American date format is relatively easy, you just swap the day and month. Accepting both formats would be quite difficult without getting input from the user on what format it is.

Comment: The capitalization is `substring`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var _d = '07231996';
_d = _d.replace(/(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{4})/, "$1-$2-$3");
document.write(new Date(_d));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Date() constructor and dateString format:

```js
let str = '23071996';

date = new Date(str.slice(-4) + '-' + str.slice(2,4) + '-' + str.slice(0,2))

console.log(date)
```